# Dynamic reference of named range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list with two items: HUN and EN, this is named as LIST. I also have two other cells named as HUN.L_LANG and EN.L_LANG, and I'd like to fill a cell dynamically based on the selected list item. So if the HUN is selected, then I'd like to fill the cell with the value of HUN.L_LANG, something like this: ="Value of LIST".L_LANG.

Is this possible? I haven't found any workaround. If it's not possible, how do you solve this task with excel formulas? Thanks!

EDIT:
I don't want to overwrite the LIST cell. So let's say LIST is in cell A1 and I'd like to fill B3 based on the selected list item either with EN.L_LANG or HUN.L_LANG.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved it with a vba function:

```
Function GetLabel(lang, name As String) As String

Dim label As String
label = lang & "." & name

GetLabel = Range(label).Value

End Function
```

And I use it like this: =GetLabel(LIST;"L_LANG")